# Unix timestamp to array of seconds indexOf

Tags: javascript, arrays, unix-timestamp

I have an array of zeros with a slot for each second of the week.

```
Array.prototype.fill=function(with,to){while(to)this[to--]=with;return this;}
var a=[].fill(0,86400);
```

when *something* happens on the particular second I would like to increment its number so over the course of many weeks (doing this over and over on the same old array) I should see where in the week is the most activity.

how do I find the place in the week in any unix time stamp **(+new Date() not new Date())**?

For example

```
+new Date();//1413740295015
```

What part can definable/used as the day? (today is Sunday)

I need to find the day: hour the minute, second but not milliseconds.

Comment: are you trying to determine the index into the array, given the current Date?

Comment: Please properly format your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to find the index into your array given the current `Date`, you can do something like the following, which determines the start of the week (Sunday at midnight) and then the seconds elapsed since that time (604,800 seconds in a week).

```
function indexFromDate(date) {
    var start = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
    return Math.floor((date - start) / 1000);
}


console.log(indexFromDate(new Date(2014, 9, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0)));             // 0
console.log(indexFromDate(new Date(2014, 9, 25, 23, 59, 59, 999)));        // 604799
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a one-liner in [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/):

```
var secondsSincestartOfWeek = moment().unix() - moment().startOf('week').unix();
```

If you can only use vanilla JS, you'll have to figure out how to determine the Unix timestamp for Sunday of the current week, and subtract that from the current timestamp. Moment.js is open source, so you could see how they do it.

By the way, it looks like your array should have 604800 elements, not 86400.

Comment: you are correct my array size is for minutes lol not seconds thanks +1